# Retrieving rss images with php using getElementsByTagName

Tags: php, xml, parsing, rss

I have this code here but it is giving me an error on the `getAttributes` line and I cant for the life of me figure out why.

This is the error message I get:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blogDepot/application/pages/myBlogs/index.php on line 58

```
<?php
$rss = new DOMDocument();

$rss->load('http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/newsonline_uk_edition/uk/rss.xml');
$feed = array();

foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'image' => $node->getElementsByTagName('thumbnail')->item(0)->getAttribute('url')
        );

    array_push($feed, $item);
}
?>
```

Comment: and line 58 is? - but anyway, please make yourself comfortable with what the error message means. It's something hard to explain in an answer, posting a question about that here often is a sign for the lack of understanding and not how things need to be done.

Comment: Hi thianks line 58 is the  'image' => $node->getElementsByTagName('thumbnail')->item(0)->getAttribute('url')

Comment: getElementsByTagName did not find a thumbnail element

Comment: Its just I am working on a project due tomorrow and this is really getting me frustrated as it is the last major thing left to do. I need it to retrieve the images in each post and the whole code works without that line that retrieves the images

Comment: @africanVoodoo did you try my answer?

Comment: you are fetching the thumbnails from $node so make sure the `<item>` elements have thumbnail children.

Comment: Who downvoted and why? At least explain ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe that is not an object, try to see if element exists:

```
'image' => $node->getElementsByTagName('thumbnail')->item(0) ? $node->getElementsByTagName('thumbnail')->item(0)->getAttribute('url') : ''
```

Comment: ok this worked! How did you do that? Does it first check if the element exists and then goes through the code? Also there are 2 media :thumbnail entries one with a normal sized image and one with a smaller; is there a way to specify which to grab? the only difference between them is the width and height

Comment: but as the element definately exists why didnt it just run through the code?

Comment: Maybe one of them was lacking thumbnail attribute .. ?

Comment: no they both have it, I downloaded and am looking through the raw code to sort of orient myself and it has 2 values like this <media:thumbnail width="66" height="49" url="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/63344000/jpg/_63344171_aprilschooluniform.jpg"/>  
      <media:thumbnail width="144" height="81" url="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/63344000/jpg/_63344887_aprilschooluniform.jpg"/>

Comment: well they have closing tags as well just it didnt copy->paste

Comment: If php returns `Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object in ...` it means there was something wrong with that object ..

Comment: it works fine now, it is displaying the image, but there r 2 image values and I wanted to know how to specify which to use so I could always use the larger thumbnail

Comment: Instead of `item(0)` try with `item(1)` on that line if they are 2 with same name

Comment: yep that did it. Now I am sure some other rss feeds would have just 1 image, would this code still work if it is set to item(1)?

Comment: ok thanks.This really helped alot, trying to see if there is a add friend in stack overflow just incase I need help again ;P

Comment: nope, no such feature :), you ask when you have any problems and someone will help you understand when you go wrong.