# How to make an RSS feed with multiple RSS sources?

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

Picking up from [a closed Stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769712/retrieving-rss-images-with-php-using-getelementsbytagname), How can this be modified to use more than one RSS source and print a list of the most recent posts from a mass (5-10) of RSS addresses? Adding more comma separated doesn't work on it.

(Note: this code still works on WordPress blogs, Aug 2017)

```
<?php
$rss = new DOMDocument();

$rss->load('http://the .rsss or .xmls');
$feed = array();

foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'image' => $node->getElementsByTagName('thumbnail')->item(0)->getAttribute('url')
        );

    array_push($feed, $item);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your rss urls in an array and iterate over each of them as follows:

```
  $rss_urls = array(
    'http://firsturl.rss',
    'http://secondurl.rss',
    'http://thirdurl.rss',
  );


  $feed = array();

  foreach($rss_urls as $rss_url){

    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load($rss_url);

    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
      $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'image' => $node->getElementsByTagName('thumbnail')->item(0)->getAttribute('url')
      );

      array_push($feed, $item);
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Did this work for you? For me, this just breaks the page at the point where I put it.

Comment: I made a modification, please try again. I did not get to test it because I do not have the necessary parameters to support this script. But it is very straight forward. Did you change the urls in the array? any errors?

Comment: When I just put that code (after entering php of course), it just does nothing (because firsturl.rss is of course not an rss), but when I put in any rss (I tried a ton, not just .xmls but with just .rss's only, it breaks the page at that point.